# Access static library embeded in iOS app from framework in the same app

Tags: ios, frameworks, static-libraries

Is it possible to access the symbols from a static library added to an iOS app from a framework added in the same app.

I am trying to build an ios framework which has dependeny on a thirdparty static library which the customer buys. So the customer adds the static library to the app.

But my framework needs to read the symbols from the static library added in the app.

Any pointers will be much appreciated.

--
Thanks,
Syed Yusuf

Answer (score 1):

You should link your framework against that static library to do that. Otherwise, you can't access that static libraries' symbols. Because they are embedded in your customer's application.

Comment: I think linking cause duplicate symbol if the user also have that in their app

Comment: Customers do not need to link that static library against their application. They only need to link against U'suf's framework since it already includes symbols they need.

Answer (score 0):

Using 'Cocoapods' as a dependency manager will get you where you want:

For example - a framework that uses the Alamofire networking framework:

1. Create your framework project
2. Use Cocoapods and add 'pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'' to your podfile.
3. Build your framework and add it to the project that intends to use this framework.
4. In you app project also add 'pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0' to your podfile

That's it.

By the way - if your app project will not add the dependent framework to its podfile, you'll see a linker error upon building the app which will look something like that:

*"dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8B381B5F-6B86-4CDD-8A49-E0CBF9C04786/test.app/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework
  Reason: image not found"*

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: If the third party framework is manual install only then is there any other way to do?

Comment: If it's manually installed I can't think of a good solution (but that's just me... maybe I'm missing something here).